# How to understand these lines in apache.log

Tags: log-files

I just get **19000** lines like these in the apache.log file for my site **example.com**.

My hosting provider shut down the hosting and notified me that I need to avoid to activate my hosting again.

I understand that I got a big amount of visits but I don't know how to avoid this.

```
    88.190.47.233 - - [27/Jun/2013:09:51:34 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 389 "http://example.com/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.02" 417
88.190.47.233 - - [27/Jun/2013:09:51:34 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 389 "http://example.com/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.02" 417
175.44.28.155 - - [27/Jun/2013:09:51:44 +0200] "GET /en/user/register HTTP/1.1" 403 503 "http://example.com/en/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)" 248
175.44.29.140 - - [27/Jun/2013:09:53:19 +0200] "GET /en/node/1557?page=2 HTTP/1.0" 403 517 "http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.12 Safari/535.11" 491
```

These are the lines from apache-error.log. There are more than 35000 lines like this.

```
[Thu Jun 27 09:50:58 2013] [error] [client 5.39.19.183] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:03 2013] [error] [client 125.112.29.105] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/en/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=1#comment-701
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=1#comment-701
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=1#comment-701
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.htm denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=1#comment-701
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.htm denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:34 2013] [error] [client 88.190.47.233] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.htm denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:51:44 2013] [error] [client 175.44.28.155] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/en/
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:19 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=2
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:20 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=2
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:20 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=2
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:20 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.htm denied, referer: http://example.com/en/node/1557?page=2
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:21 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:21 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:21 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.htm denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:22 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:22 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:53:22 2013] [error] [client 175.44.29.140] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.htm denied, referer: http://example.com/
[Thu Jun 27 09:56:53 2013] [error] [client 113.246.6.147] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/en/
[Thu Jun 27 09:58:58 2013] [error] [client 108.62.71.180] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied, referer: http://example.com/
```

Comment: Those lines look like perfectly normal connections to me. Have you by any chance been slashdotted, or your site in some other way referred to online at a place that will generate a lot of traffic?

Comment: Your hosting provider shut you down just like that? They didn't offer to migrate you to a higher plan or something like that? If so, I'd say its time to find a better provider.

Answer (score 3):

Those lines are perfectly normal showing who performed what type of request (GET request in your case) and what the result was (403 -> forbidden).

If your hosting provider says you have too many influx then either those requests are malicious (DDoS) or they are legitimate (you've got a popular website). If it's the latter one then I suggest upgrading your hosting plan or changing provider.

**EDIT**

The error log means that you have a file (or might not have file) named index.php in the root of your web folder, but that you have defined rules which forbid clients from accessing that file. This can either be in your apache configuration files or in a .htaccess. Because you do not allow these pages to be accessed, it logs a violation of these rules.

So first of all try to see if you actually have an index.php and why you have defined rules in your apache configuration which disallow this behavior. If appropriate remove them, another solution is to rewrite the URL from your /index.php to some other page.

Comment: my mistake. I copy the lines from apache.log. I just updated my question with the line from the apache.error.log file

Comment: The website is powered by Drupal. These rules are defined in the .htaccess but they all are needed for the Drupal system. Should I open this question in drupal.stackexchange.com ?